# How to construct "inaccessible hypernatural"?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis

Consider that, take a sufficient large natural number $a_1$, then take a natural number $a_2$ sufficient large to $a_1$, then take $a_3$,...
Now we have a function $n \mapsto a_n$ which grows very fast. We can use this function to produce large number, such as $a_{a_1}$,$a_{a_{..._{a_1}}}$($a_1$s a).
I wish that there would be a nonstandard extension to describe it.

Formally, let $U=V_\omega (\mathbb{N})$, construct $U'$ and a map $*:U\rightarrow U'$ satisfies transfer principle, and that:

Let $M$ be the set of all maps $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, then there exists a $f\in\ ^*M$ such that $f(0)=1$ and for any $g\in M$, $m,n\in \mathbb{^*N}$, $m<n$, we have $^*g(f(m))<f(n)$.

Comment: One can in fact have infinitely many levels of nonstandardness. This is Hrbacek's specialty. See discussion [here](http://msupress.org/journals/issue/?id=50-21D-61F).

Comment: It seems to me that traditional "richness" requirements for a nonstandard model (e.g., enlargement, or $\kappa$-saturation for some cardinal $\kappa$ greater than the continuum) will imply what you want. The point is that, for any **finitely** many standard $g$'s, a suitable $f$ exists (even in the standard world), so richness (of any of these sorts) will provide a nonstandard $f$ that works for all standard $g$'s simultaneously.